# Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'i'

Tags: angular

One small issue plz help

> Template parse errors:\nCan't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'i'.

```
<i class="dropdown-icon btn-outline-warning icmn-spinner11"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rerun_modal"
    data-name="{{ingestion_info.ingestion.name}}"
    [attr.data-target]="'#rerun_modal_' + ingestion_info.ingestion.name"
    (click)=" name = ingestion_info.ingestion.name; password=''; is_alive = false">
    Rerun
</i>
```

Comment: You should accept the answer if it helped you. Or let us know if you need anything more

Comment: Why not accept the answer if it worked for you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, angular compiler is trying to tell you that there is no property name on  tag.

If you have to pass this name attribute to controller, you will have to pass it an input

```
<i class="dropdown-icon btn-outline-warning icmn-spinner11"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rerun_modal"
    data-name="{{ingestion_info.ingestion.name}}"
    [attr.data-target]="'#rerun_modal_' + ingestion_info.ingestion.name"
    (click)=" [name] = 'ingestion_info.ingestion.name'; password=''; is_alive = false">
    Rerun
</i>
```

or just use attribute binding

```
[attr.data-name]="ingestion_info.ingestion.name"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since angular treats `data-name` as `name` binding and `i` element doesn't have `name` property you can fix it by using attribute binding:

```
attr.data-name="{{ingestion_info.ingestion.name}}"
```

or

```
[attr.data-name]="ingestion_info.ingestion.name"
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, this is clearly correct.. +1